# ¿Como hago para comparar strings en un fragment en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

De antemano les doy las gracias por la ayuda tengo un fragment que recibe de otro frament un texto. Y ese texto lo quiero comparar con un `String` pero al ponerlo dentro del fragment en la parte:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_arroz, container, false);
```

no se ejecuta el código de comparación es este:

```
String hora1 = pruevacomparar.getText().toString();
if (hora1.contentEquals("aba")){
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"prueva",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no prueva",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

pero si pongo este código dentro de un botón, si me lo compara.

Lo que necesito es que me lo compare fuera del botón al iniciar o al llamar el fragment.

Muchas gracias

Comment: como envias el dato de fragment a fragment??

Comment: Es importante responder a las preguntas que realiza la comunidad, te sugiero agregues como estas obteniendo pruevacomparar? como envias y como recibe de otro fragment un texto?, saludos.